# How to restore GRUB after restoring MBR with boot-repair?

Tags: grub2, windows-7, mbr, boot-repair

I've a problem after upgrading to 12.10, which is when I choose Windows option from boot options, I got "A disk read error occurred" error.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/) to restore MBR, but the problem now that the Grub is gone and it boots directly to Windows 7.

What should I do now to restore both Windows 7 & Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You could always download and use [Resc-a-tux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

This is a live cd with a primary goal: Restoring grub/installing grub.
It's a nice program which I used after windows just removed my grub without asking, and it worked like a charm.

> **Rescatux features:**
>
> Fixes GRUB and GRUB2
>
> Regenerates Debian/Ubuntu grub menues
>
> Check and fix filesystems
>
> Fixes Windows MBR
>
> Blank Windows passwords
>
> Boot Info Script
>
> Change Gnu/Linux password
>
> Regenerate sudoers file
>
> **Extra tools:**
>
> Synaptic
>
> Gparted 0.7

Comment: Looks nice, I think I'll put in the pxe boot of our Linux User Group. SO far we always did stuff manually changerooting from LiveCDs and stuff. Creeps people out sometimes.

Comment: What group are you referring to?
But it's all a matter of what you are used too, if you never worked with terminal, it can be scary, but after a while, you stop caring. :P

Comment: I usually hang around at LinuxWorks! in Berlin ;-) There is probably a LUG near your place too. Many of us are quite adept in terminal usage, but Linux (Ubuntu in particular) is very slowly becoming a mainstream OS here and we sometimes get very novice visitors.

Comment: Ahh I see, well, I googled, only 1 big thing here in Holland, but I can't find out where it is....
Well, I hope people can use resc-a-tux as an alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `Boot-Repair`, and click `Advanced Options`.

1. If the `GRUB reinstall` option is available, tick it, and click `Apply`.
2. If the `GRUB reinstall` option is **not** available, that means that your Ubuntu upgrade has failed and broke your Ubuntu system files. Then fix your Ubuntu system files via a Ubuntu12.10 liveCD (or liveUSB) this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation